# where to find examples of qt cockpit?

Tags: qt, widget, qt4

I've been given a task to design a GUI of an airplane cockpit. I'm using `Qt4`. Does anyone know where I can find cockpit widgets? Maybe someone can point me to a library they used before.  Ideally, it would be nice to have a plugin library so that I could use it with a Qt Designer. I found [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qfi/) but I can't figure out how to use it with `Qt`.

Comment: What exactly don't you know about `QFlightInstruments`? It's a rather typical Qt project. The easiest way to use it is to add `qfi.qrc` and all the `src/qfi_` files to your own project.

Comment: @KubaOber I'm somewhat new to Qt. I haven't found any tutorials on how to add previously created widgets to Qt. I would really appreciate if you could give me a step by step on how to to add them to Qt Creator.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/), they have (among many other things) [nice controls](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/controlscreenshots.html).

For example, these ones:
[image]

As far as I remember, the integration with an existing Qt project is really quick. I never used it with Qt Designer, though, but a plugin seems to exist.